# Regex first letter not integer with jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

I have textbox and I want get string value. But I want users to not be able to enter the string that has number on first letter. As matter of fact I want to replace number with `''` null.

for example

```
1test  =====convert=======>  test
```

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript, just keep JS tag (along with regex).

Comment: @Tushar it's my humble request [don't use comments for answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and give other a chance at least to update their answer , if answers are already their  :)

Comment: @PavneetSingh: It is not so easy to change one's habits. Just ask Tushar to remove the comment, or ask to post an answer.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vM8U9/24/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is asked many times. Dup-Hammer

Comment: @Tushar: I know, but I cannot find a good dupe to close this one with.

Comment: @PavneetSingh For now, I've removed my comments. I don't mind if anyone use my comments to answer question as long as it is well-answered(explained, examples, alternatives, etc.) and I'm too lazy to add answer.

Comment: @Tushar thanks , it's humble of you though everyone can't think and type as fast as you and others pro guys ( sonic ) in every area and some times i have seen answerers don't get much votes if the answer is already in the comment though i respect and appreciate helpful nature (whole world needs it so badly) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `^[a-zA-Z]`

`^` starts with  a-z or A-Z

or if you want special character too then use `^\D`

`^\D` : Matches anything other than a decimal digit

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Ur9R1R/1)

you can use `$text.replace(/^[^0-9]+/, '')`

`/^` beginning of the line

`[^0-9]+` match anything other than digits at-least once

thanks @ Wiktor and Tushar

Comment: OP didn't tell that he didn't want _ or & at the beginning

Comment: @TheLostMind i know and i listed the case as well

Answer (score 1):

This works your case:

```
^\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/daezA9/1

^ asserts position at start of the string

\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

Comment: You misunderstood the question. OP wants opposite.

Comment: @Tushar - OP could *negate* this regex :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution: You can check on this live regex.

https://regex101.com/r/OJfyv4/1

```
$re = '/\b[a-z][a-z0-9]*/';
$str = '1test';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Lets say that site is down.

Comment: @Tushar: so will he use that site all time? He will just check the example.

Comment: What I mean is, you should include the answer here at-least the regex with explanation. Add the link for reference only.

Comment: @Tushar: That is choice of user, just because of this reason can't downvote. Though i have updated.